# Refresh Token AWS Cognito User Pool

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I think we can all agree that the documentation of AWS is *sparse*.

I have a client using Cognito with the PHP AWS SDK for authentication and that part works fine.  They can authenticate and get their access token no problem.  When the access token expires and we attempt to refresh, the token is always invalid.  I have even tried to log in and then immediately use that refresh token and it's still an "Invalid Refresh Token".  The client is not using a client secret on this particular application.  See the code:

```
$cognitoClient->adminInitiateAuth([
    'AuthFlow' => 'REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH',
    'AuthParameters' => [
        'USERNAME' => $username,
        'REFRESH_TOKEN' => $refreshToken
    ],
    'ClientId' => self::CLIENT_ID,
    'UserPoolId' => self::USER_POOL_ID,
]);
```

The exact same code works for password auth.  Does anyone know what I'm missing?  I prefer Google's services as they seem to have better documentation, but this client has some attachment to AWS, so switching is out of the question.  Any help is appreciated because the documentation is none at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the devices turned on for your pool, if yes then you need to pass in the Device Key. Otherwise can you please PM me your requestId, userPoolId and timeframe, I will be happy to look deeper into it.

Comment: It turned out it was devices.  I had just started randomly changing settings in my user pool until something worked.  I'll mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Was there a resolution on this other than DeviceID?